# Generic wrapper method for Play! models

Tags: java, generics, annotations, playframework

I'm trying to implement a RESTful interface for my Play! framework models using a generic wrapper.

I want to use a generic method to call and return each model's respective "find" methods.

```
private static <T extends GenericModel> void getModel(T model, Params params){
if (params._contains("id")){
  renderJSON(model.findById(params.get("id", Long.class)));
}
else{
  renderJSON(model.findAll());
}
```

}

The above method is called as follows, in my controller's GET method according to which model is requested through a particular route:

```
getModel(new User(), params);
```

Since the *find()* methods are actually static methods of the GenericModels class, it should entirely be possible. However, since Play generates the code for each defined model I get this error:

**UnsupportedOperationException occured : Please annotate your JPA model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation.**

At least, I think that's why. Is there no way around this? Am I forced to tediously implement the same GET, PUT, UPDATE, DELETE methods for each class?

Answer (score 1):

I think "model.findById" calls the GenericModel.findById static function which is not implemented and generates the exception. It doesn't call the static function enhanced by JPAPlugin at runtime.

I'm not sure it will work but you should try to call directly JPQL function, something like:

```
private static <T extends GenericModel> void getModel(Class<T> clazz, Params params){
if (params._contains("id")){
  renderJSON(JPQL.instance.findById(clazz.getSimpleName(), params.get("id", Long.class)));
}
else{
  renderJSON(model.findAll());
}
```

and call it like the following:

```
getModel(new User(), User.class, params);
```

Comment: JPQL appears to throw the same error. It seems that code Play generates for models is not accessible at all when using Generics. Thanks for the answer anyway. Although it would be more elegant to use a generic wrapper/method, it seems concrete is the only way to go.

Comment: basically the model bytecode is enhanced at runtime and the GenericModel.findById function is replaced by a new one at YourClass level. So as it is static and as static functions are not "overridable", it certainly calls the one it can find at compilation which the one in GenericModel :(... Sorry if my solution was not good ;)!

Comment: It seems to be a limitation of the framework, not your code. So no worries.

Comment: I would say it's a limitation on Java itself :D

Comment: Yes, I do wish Python was more popular in the enterprise domain, then I'd only be using that.

Comment: I'm currently trying Scala and I'm quite happy: this is a static typed language which I loved much more than dynamic languages ;)